# Spannable в сочетании с Html.fromHtml делает произвольный сдвиг

Tags: java, android, html, textview, spannable

В общем, проблема такая:

У меня есть `Spannable` весь текст которого проходит также и`Html` форматирование:

```
private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(str);
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);

int idx1 = str.indexOf("[");
int idx2 = 0;

while (idx1 != -1) {
    idx2 = str.indexOf("]", idx1) + 1;

    String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);

    ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {

        }
    }, idx1, idx2, 0);
    idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);
}
return ssb;
}
```

В результате, я получаю с БД текст `pageContentStr` и задаю его моему `TextView`

```
pageContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
pageContent.setText(addClickablePart(pageContentStr), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

По алгоритму обработки, во всем тексте, все что находится в квадратных скобках становится кликабельной ссылкой, и все работает правильно, но как только я задал обработку через `Html`:

```
CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(str);
```

То ссылки сдвинулись и стали отображаться некорректно:

[image: результат]

С чем это может быть связано? Если я уберу обработку `Html` все работает корректно, и ссылки подсвечиваются лишь от квадратной скобки `[`до квадратной скобки`]`.

Comment: Попробуйте делать `setSpan` с флагом `Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`

Comment: @woesss к сожалению все также

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы находите индексы меток по исходной строке. Но при обработке методом `Html.fromHtml()` теги из текста вырезаются - соответственно все оставшиеся символы "переезжают".
Вообщем нужно искать метки по тексту, полученному после обработки:

```
private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(Html.fromHtml(str));

    str = ssb.toString(); // получаем "чистый" текст

    int idx1 = str.indexOf("[");
    int idx2 = 0;

    while (idx1 != -1) {
        idx2 = str.indexOf("]", idx1) + 1;

        String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);

        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {

            }
        }, idx1, idx2, 0);
        idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);
    }
    return ssb;
}
```

Comment: Вы просто гений)